# What is wrong with my Grails deploy to Tomcat container?

Tags: tomcat, grails, amazon-ec2

I am seeing an issue where my Grails 3 web application does not start up correctly on an EC2 instance that we have successfully deployed a Grails 2 web application to. This same Grails 2 application has been upgraded to Grails 3, and is now causing the issue.

The version of Grails I am using is 3.2.4. The version of Tomcat that is being used on the EC2 instance is 8.0.20. Also, the JVM version is 1.8.0_31.

The war file is built using the Grails command `grails package` (I'm not sure if there's a difference between this and `grails war` as other Grails 3.2.4 applications package and deploy just fine using this command), and the file is subsequently placed into the Tomcat webapps directory.

This is the issue I see when starting up Tomcat:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsCacheFilter': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#2fb114b8' of type [grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.simple.MemoryPageFragmentCachingFilter] while setting bean property 'filter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2fb114b8': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setUrlMappingsHandlerMapping' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'urlMappingsHandlerMapping': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setWebRequestInterceptors' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'openSessionInViewInterceptor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateDatastore' while setting bean property 'hibernateDatastore'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This happens when I package, deploy, and start up the application using production mode only. I have tried setting the project up in a Tomcat 8 container locally, in qa mode on a different EC2 instance, and also in qa mode on an EC2 instance that was launched from an image that I made of the production instance I am trying to deploy to. I could not reproduce the issue on any of these.

I thought that it was possible that the `dataSource` in application.groovy production environment block was causing the issue. Since this particular project doesn't rely on a database, I have tried removing that and deploying the web app again in production mode on the production instance, but I still faced the same issue.

I have also tried to replicate the production `dataSource` configuration in qa mode. The project still started up correctly using qa mode with the same `dataSource` properties. I didn't see the issue appear in the Tomcat logs.

I have also read the docs a few times (particularly the deployment section), and have made sure to change the line for `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` dependency to `provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"` in build.gradle since I am not using an embedded Tomcat.

After doing some more research, I am still unsure of what could be causing this issue. Maybe there is some incompatibility with Tomcat that I am overlooking. Does anyone have any ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with my application configuration and an incompatible plugin. Both application.yml and application.groovy contained `hibernate` blocks in them. I also had an old version of the plugin `database-migration` (1.4.0). Once I removed the `hibernate` block in application.yml and removed the `database-migration` plugin, the application was deployed successfully. If you want to use the `database-migration` plugin with a Grails 3 project, you can do so with the 2.x version, according to the docs: https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-database-migration#versions.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in grails v.3.2.4. 
https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10377

Comment: I have seen this issue. This looks like it is happening with embedded Tomcat. A commenter mentions that it works when the WAR is deployed to Tomcat, but it seems to be failing when deploying the WAR to Tomcat for me. I also have not seen the FileNotFoundException in my logs. Maybe I can try to upgrade Spring Boot though.

Comment: Did you try to upgrade grails?

Comment: I haven't tried to upgrade yet. We have another Grails 3.2.4 project that we have successfully deployed to a Tomcat container, and the particular project we are working on now has already been tested end-to-end in a custom qa mode/environment. When we deploy to a qa Tomcat container in this custom mode, it works. So, I am hoping to stick with the same version for now and figure out what is going on when running in production mode.